# im having a python coding issue and need ideas

Tags: python, list

I have written a code that looks through a transaction list and sees if a company is buying or selling and converts the value to USD and then returns it. the problem is my original list looks like this:

```
 [['Acer', 481242.74], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ['Datsun', 748502.91], ['Equifax', 146517.59], ['Gerdau', 898579.89], ['Haribo', 265333.85]]
```

and when i run my code it iterates through about 100 transactions, and after each transaction returns a sample like the following:

```
['Acer', 21439.6892]
```

now my problem is i want to update the value in  the original list with this new value so that it would still have the company name but the two values behind it would be added and the new value would appear in the original list for the next iteration. so 481242.74+21439.6892=502682.4292 so the new original list would look like the following with the acer value updated

```
  [['Acer',502682.4292  ], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ['Datsun', 748502.91], ['Equifax', 146517.59], ['Gerdau', 898579.89], ['Haribo', 265333.85]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary instead to order your companies

```
d ={'Acer': 481242.74,'Beko': 966071.86, 'Cemex': 187242.16, 'Datsun': 748502.91, 'Equifax': 146517.59, 'Gerdau': 898579.89, 'Haribo': 265333.85}
for k,v in d.items():
    d[k] = v+sample[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead of a list.

```
#Make the master data structure a Dictionary
myDict = {'Acer':float(481242.74) }
print myDict

#iterate over the newList and update the master dictionary
newList = [['Acer', float(502682.4292)]]
for Company, NewValue in newList:
    myDict[Company]=(myDict[Company]+NewValue)
print myDict
```